# Does WebDriverWait really work?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, wait, thread-sleep

Does `WebDriverWait` really helps when most of the time more viable solution I found to be useful are other explicit wait methods mostly thread.sleep() Java method in Selenium? There are situations where for one test after another it requires to wait for some dynamic image to finish loading(disappear). I used commands like

```
wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(
        "//td[contains(@class,'x-grid3-td-editCustomComposite')]/div/img[contains(@src,'/icons/wait.gif')]"
    )));
```

and then print a success message to check it is shown only after image no longer appear

but the `Selenium Webdriver` doesn't wait and jumps onto the next instruction causing Test to fail

Comment: what is the next instruction that is failing?

Comment: Use `visibilityOfElementLocated` rather than `invisibilityOfElementLocated` if you wish to wait for an element to appear.

Comment: Yes I understand but rather I want to wait for an element to disappear!

Comment: Problem is that there is no timeout exception and test moves onto the next  statement in test script hence the test doesn't wait for image element to finish appearing. There is no error or exception, its just that the wait doesn't happen. This image is a gif and keeps on running till a time period (vary from few seconds to 2-3 minutes). I have to explicitly wait out this duration by using thread.sleep() method, only then test works!